# sharethis module in drupal

Tags: social-network

I am using [Share this](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) module in Drupal . In that when we click on Facebook, Linkedin the image is also inserted and linked to that social site but when we click on twitter,no image is pulled in.Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Twitter validator tool](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) for possible reason. The Twitter [specification](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-setup/advertiser-card-specifications.html) may help you as well.